# how to get coordinate on the table from mouse click

Tags: javascript, php, css

Please, look at this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI8Fk.png).

I would like to display lat and lg, respectively upon mouse click.

```
<div id="info_table"> 
  <form name="xyPoinnt"> 
      <table border="2"> 
          <tbody> 
      <tr> 
          <td><center>lat</center></td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" size="20" /><td> 
      </tr> 

      <tr> 
          <td><center>lg</center></td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" size="20" /></td> 
      </tr> 
          </tbody> 
      </table> 
  </form> 
  </div>
```

here is my code related to the table.

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(pMarker[i], 'click', function(inerKey) {
                return function() {

                    pInfowindow[inerKey].open(map, pMarker[inerKey]);
                }

   }(i))
```

code about this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CtZh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e){

  document.getElementById("lat").innerText= e.latLng.lat();
  document.getElementById("lng").innerText= e.latLng.lng();
});
```

Comment: it 's weired. when i tried it in IE , it worked but it doesn't work in Chrome